# How to add two break'<br>' tag using nl2br() in php?

Tags: php

I am using **nl2br()** function  for insert `<br>` tag.

Now I want to insert two `<br>` tags. Is it possible?

Comment: use  nl2br() two times

Comment: try `$string =nl2br(nl2br($string));`

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
$string = str_replace("<br>", "<br><br>", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

nl2br will add `<br />` to newline, replace `<br />` by `str_replace`

If you want to add `<br>` , you can add second parameter FALSE to tell function this is not xhtml.

```
nl2br($yourContent, FALSE)
```

like this:

```
str_replace('<br>', '<br><br>',nl2br($yourContent, FALSE));
```

Or this:

```
str_replace('<br />', '<br /><br />',nl2br($yourContent));
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
So that works for me:

```
$test = nl2br(nl2br("The nutty pearl barley,
sweetly caramelised carrots and heady garlic combine to make these simple ingredients
into a seriously special dinner. (Serves 4) 46p a portion 4 carrots, diced, 40p 2 tsp
")); 

echo $test;
```

ORIGINAL POST (Wich is wrong ahah)

You could do that

```
$string = nl2br($string);
$string = str_replace('<br>', '<br><br>', $string);
```

or

```
$string = nl2br($string);
$string = str_replace('<br />', '<br /><br />', $string);
```

Comment: I used it but it is not replacing.
Tried to replace 4 br to 2br like this
str_replace('<br><br><br><br>', '<br><br>', nl2br($string));

Comment: That's weird, i can't help you more sorry ^^'

Comment: Try this in phpcodeonline
 $test = nl2br((nl2br("The nutty pearl barley, sweetly caramelised carrots and heady garlic combine to make these simple ingredients into a seriously special dinner.

(Serves 4) 46p a portion
4 carrots, diced, 40p

2 tsp mixed dried herbs, 6p
300g pearl barley, 33p


Add the carrots to a large saute pan with two tablespoons of oil. Fry on a medium-high heat for 10 minutes, until the edges start to caramelise.
Add the onions, garlic, mushrooms and mixed herbs, with the rest of "))); 
echo str_replace("<br>","test", $test );